# I added aliases to user ~/.bashrc but “sudo -u user -i 'alias_name'” still reports “command not found”?

Tags: linux, bash, alias, sudo

As a trivial example, in user foo's ~/.bashrc there is an alias;

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

Using sudo I can see the alias is set;

```
bar@laptop:~$ sudo -u foo -i alias ll
alias ll=`ls -l'
```

But, I can't actually use the alias;

```
 bar@laptop:~$ sudo -u foo -i ll
 -bash: ll: command not found
```

Commands that are bash functions work, OK.  Is there a way to get the aliases to work also?

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

http://www.shellperson.net/using-sudo-with-an-alias/

Comment: This works for 'foo' logged in locally, but doesn't work for user 'bar' trying to 'su -u foo'.

Comment: @CAB: The article Gor linked to explains why. The trailing space trick only helps if the argument immediately following the first aliased command is also an alias. If you say `sudo -i ll`, Bash sees that `-i` is not an alias, so it stops expanding aliases and executes the built command. You're probably going to have to turn your second alias into a script or shell function to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great example of how to do this [in the Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Passing_aliases). Add the follwoing to your .bashrc

```
alias sudo="sudo "
```

Don't ask me why it works. I've scoured my man pages looking for this without luck, but it's never failed me yet.

```
> sudo ll
total 60
drwxr-xr-x  2 brice users 4096 Feb  4 16:17 classes
drwxr-xr-x  3 brice users 4096 Mar  6 21:48 Desktop
drwx------  6 brice users 4096 Mar 28 21:32 Downloads
drwx------ 25 brice users 4096 Mar 29 21:20 Dropbox
drwxr-xr-x  2 brice users 4096 Mar 11 20:27 scripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 brice users 4096 Mar 19 21:59 tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you add

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

then go ahead and add your custom alias ... for eg. if regular command is

```
sudo rm ~/qwerty/removethis.txt
```

alias for above command will look like

```
alias your_custom_alias='sudo rm ~/qwerty/removethis.txt'
```